Compare $\left(39^{2024} + 79^{2024}\right)^{2025}$ and $\left(39^{2025} + 79^{2025}\right)^{2024}$
This is a grade 6 problem, so we cannot use anything other than basic natural number operations.
Compare $\left(39^{2024} + 79^{2024}\right)^{2025}$ and $\left(39^{2025} + 79^{2025}\right)^{2024}$.
I tried: 39<40 and  79<80 therefore the left number is less than  $\left(40^{2024} + 80^{2024}\right)^{2025} = 40^{2024}\left(1 + 2^{2024}\right)^{2025}$ but since 79 and 39 have no common divisor other than 1, I got stuck.

Please edit you include your efforts.  Note:  I am quite surprised that this was presented to sixth graders.

@lulu I am critical of your comment, which others have upvoted.  On the one hand, your comment represents a common reaction at MathSE that (I feel) is generally appropriate.  On the other hand, your comment assumes that 6th graders have been given some tools to attack the problem (i.e. worked examples, previously solved problems, proven theorems).  I have no idea what the problem composer was thinking.  Absent the necessary (pre-calculus) tools, I feel that it is not reasonable to ask the original poster to show work.  You can not work on a problem without the proper tools.

@user2661923  First of all, the OP added the bit at the end in response to my comment...the original version showed no effort of any sort.  More to the point, it isn't like the OP is actually in the sixth grade...here is one of their prior questions.  They've been on the site for $5$ years...I think some context is to be expected.  They could, for instance, attack it with more advanced methods though, as I pointed out below, brute force computation really doesn't work here.

@lulu Good point about the OP editing the posted question after your comment.  However, I disagree about what the OP is expected to do.  By announcing that this is a grade 6 problem, the OP is announcing that all methods unavailable to grade 6 students must be considered off limits.  Therefore, it is not appropriate for the OP to show work involving advanced methods.  That is pointless, since the posted question is not asking for any available solution.  Instead, the posted question is asking for a solution that might reasonably be conjured by 6th graders.

Factor out $79^{2024\times 2025}$ from each expression, yielding $$79^{2024\times 2025}\times \left(\left(\frac {39}{79}\right)^{2024}+1\right)^{2025}\quad \quad \& \quad \quad 79^{2024\times 2025}\times \left(\left(\frac {39}{79}\right)^{2025}+1\right)^{2024}$$
Clearly the big factor has no impact on the comparison, so we can ignore it.
Now,
$$\frac {39}{79}<1 \implies \left (\frac {39}{79}\right)^{2025}<\left (\frac {39}{79}\right)^{2024}$$
But, of course,  $x>y>1\implies x^{2025}>y^{2024}$ so we see that the left hand expression is greater.

+1 : This is really nice, especially considering that calculus is probably off limits to 6th graders.

@user2661923  Still don't think a whole lot of sixth graders will work it out.  Wolfram Alpha struggles to distinguish between the numbers...they are awfully close.

A sixth grader may well be able to follow your analysis.  However, see also the comment that I left following your comment, after the posted question.

How are you able to think of these "out of the box solutions"....really simple to understand, but coming up with them is really hard...kudos

So I find another solution:
$\left(39^{2024}+79^{2024}\right)^{2025} =\left(39^{2024}+79^{2024}\right)^{2024}\cdot\left(39^{2024}+79^{2024}\right)> \left(39^{2024}+79^{2024}\right)^{2024}\cdot79^{2024} =\left((39\cdot 79)^{2024}+79^{2025}\right)^{2024}>\left(39^{2025}+79^{2025}\right)^{2024}$.
